# Playing Raw H264 video in HTML

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Does anyone know of a way to play .h264 in it's raw format in HTML? Tried using the  tags, but it says video / mime type not supported.

Annoyingly, I'm not able to convert the files into different format (long story..). Tried the normal google routes, but no luck.

Comment: Or even a means of converting on-the-fly, though I'd imaging that would be pretty resource-heavy on the server side..

Comment: *Raw*? Why isn't it in a container like mp4?

Comment: Basically I've got low spec old hardware recording video constantly, saving it as different files. When I used avconv / ffmpeg, it started corrupting things. Long story short, I made everything around this raw format, and should have thought of the final front-end, but didn't. So it has to be in raw :(

Comment: as far as I know no chance...mp4 is for IE and Safari, webM for Chrome and Firefox. You need to convert first. Free webM video converter lets you convert into both formats. Also from mpeg4(h.264)

Comment: You can find answer from this post.
[How to embed .h264 video file in html webpage using video tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487978/how-to-embed-h264-video-file-in-html-webpage-using-video-tags)

Comment: Though it is old question but it is worth sharing for the users who are still struggling with playing of raw h264 in browser. Recently I have developed a mp4 muxer that is able to play raw h264 video. Check this project https://github.com/samirkumardas/jmuxer