# How to embed .h264 video file in html webpage using video tags

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, h.264, mp4

I am trying to play **.h264** file in browser, Trying to accomplish this using html video tags. The result is always an empty frame.

I did check some links on web, They recommend to play the video in **.mp4** container.

Can someone help me to accomplish this?

UPDATED CODE:

```html
<video width="560" height="340" preload controls>

  <source src="hh.h264" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
   <!--<source src="hh.mov" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
 <source src="hh.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
 <source src="hh.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />-->



</video>
```

References:

[How do i play H264 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789838/how-do-i-play-h264-video/2789962#2789962)

[Play .h264 files webplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076088/play-h264-files-webplayer)

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html#fbid=6u-u00TH7Je

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I just updated with code. I also tried some javascript for compatibility.

Comment: Would you mind supplying the urls for hh?

Comment: Ya sure, This is the url https://s3.amazonaws.com/201501bk/20150115122429.h264 Thanks

Comment: I thought you had a file that used a video coding format (codec) H264 but I didn't realize you were dealing with a file with a .h264 file extension. The problem is that .h264 is not a valid extension for video, H264 is a video codec. It will never play this way. Check here for all valid video file extensions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format

Comment: Have to agree with JoeR, a web browser will not play a raw .264 file. It must be put into a container such as mp4. If it is live video, many moderns browsers can use media source extensions to play a fragmented mp4 (m4s)

Comment: Okay, but the thing is I need to play the video in android device(android default browser). What is the approach for converting the raw .264 file into mp4 container? Any article or links will be very much helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include h.264 in your html code, you only need to include the path to your video file and the video file name. So, let's say your video file is .mp4 and your file's name is `myvideo.mp4` and your `myvideo.mp4` is in a folder named `videos` and your html file is just outside that `videos` folder in your project folder then this is what you have to do:

```
<video width="560" controls>
  <source src="videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This will work, provided your video is encoded in mp4 format. The h264 is a codec and it's completely irrelevant in this situation.

You should first find an mp4 encoder online, there are many free encoders, encode your video to .mp4 then use the html code above and your video will play fine.

Comment: I am trying to somehow play the src file in the browser such that it can play in android browser. Is it not necessary to mention type="video/h264" ? I tried with mp4 as mentioned in the code above. but no luck.

Comment: @Ramaraju.d  this is my comment from earlier: I thought you had a file that used a video coding format (codec) H264 but I didn't realize you were dealing with a file with a .h264 file extension. The problem is that .h264 is not a valid extension for video, H264 is a video codec. It will never play this way. Check here for all valid video file extensions: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format

Comment: @Ramaraju.d my answer was based on the assumption that you actually have the video file and you are able to convert it into an mp4 file. However, the .h264 file extension is not valid. That file, the way it is, won't play anywhere.

Comment: Ohh ya understood now. Thank you very much for your clear explanation :-)

Comment: @JoeR You are wrong about .h264 not playing anywhere. If the raw .h264 video stream is in a byte-stream format such as Annex B you can play it very well, just not in a browser with only HTML5.

Comment: @aergistal Please read my comment again and don't quote me out of context. This is what I said: "That file, the way it is, won't play anywhere." you missed the important part "the way it is". That video file won't play anywhere the way it is with that file extension. That's why the OP couldn't play it.

Comment: @JoeR: "That video file won't play anywhere the way it is with that file extension". Yes it will, but not in a browser without a plugin. Eg: the VLC browser plugin will read a H.264 raw stream in Annex B.

Comment: @aergistal not with the .h264 file extension

Comment: @JoeR `<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" target="test.h264" />` where test.h264 is a raw H.264 byte-stream. Do you want screenshots?

Answer (score 4):

The **.h264** file contains the raw H.264 stream which is not directly supported in browsers. You can use a tool like `FFmpeg` to put it in a container like the other answers recommended:

`ffmpeg -f h264 -i test.h264 -c:v copy test.mp4`

**Edit:**

If you *must* play a raw H.264 byte-stream then you need a browser plugin. Example for VLC web plugin:

`<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" target="test.h264" />`

Comment: afaik, VLC plugin no longer works in modern browsers, does it ?

Comment: @PypeBros it uses NPAPI which is almost phased out, so yes, it's dead Jim. Not that it was a good idea to rely on a web plugin in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an HTML5 video player around broadway h264 codec (emscripten) that can play live (no delay) h264 video on all browsers (desktop, iOS, ...).

Video stream is sent through websocket to the client, decoded frame per frame and displayed in a canva (using webgl for acceleration)

Check out https://github.com/131/h264-live-player on github.

Comment: In my experience Broadway does not perform well in Internet Explorer. Even IE11.

Comment: Unfortunately Broadway can only work with h.264 baseline profile.