# How to enable autoplay .h264 video in html

Tags: html, h.264, qualtrics, autoplay

I am trying to get a h.264 video to autoplay in Qualtrics. Here is the HTML code for the video (I've removed the source from the code).

```
<video class="qmedia" controls="true" height="480" preload="auto" width="640"><source src="blah" type="video/mp4" /><embed align="middle" autoplay="true" bgcolor="white" class="qmedia" controller="true" height="480" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" src="blah" type="video/quicktime" width="640" /></video>
```

I've tried autoplay ="true" and autoplay ="autoplay" and adding < video autoplay> to the end of the code. None of these have caused the video to autoplay. Does anyone know how to enable this in the HTML?

Comment: It is not possible to run raw h264 without muxing to mp4. You can check this project https://github.com/samirkumardas/jmuxer

Answer (score 0):

autoplay and controls are both just true if they exist, no need to set them equal to anything. The following worked fine in my test:

```
<video class="qmedia" controls autoplay height="480" preload="auto" width="640">
<source src="blah.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<embed align="middle" autoplay="true" bgcolor="white" class="qmedia" controller="true" height="480" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" src="blah.mov" type="video/quicktime" width="640" />
</video>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are attempting to use a .h264 video not a .mp4 it won't work. .h264 does exist, and can be played, but not by the native html5 video player. See the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487978/how-to-embed-h264-video-file-in-html-webpage-using-video-tags